# auto change position vertical submenu dynamically in angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have a vertical menu with submenus that hide at the bottom,
I need a solution that allows you to change the position of the submenu dynamically upwards but keeps the organization of the menu for example if you open the last item of the menu it must be next to the last item of the sub- menu, the goal is to always display all the submenus.

I tried this style but when I open the first menu item the submenus are hidden at the top :

```
    .sat-popover-container.sat-popover-after.sat-popover-below {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
     }
```

Comment: A div with position absolute should be "enclosed" in a div with position relative

Comment: @Eliseo Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to apply your solution but it didn't work, can you please explain to me a little?